# How to Trim right and left a String in VB .net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to take the value of 
`T.GS.+0.220kg`
but I don't know how to remove the string. 
I just want to take numbers from the weight.
like `0.220`

Can someone help me ?

Comment: If you have always the same pattern, you can just `Dim result As String = "T.GS.+0.220kg".Trim("T.GS.+kg".ToCharArray())`. The strings (value and pattern) can be variables, of course.

Comment: @Jimi that still working thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the Regular Expressions to extract a decimal value from basically any string. First you'd need to import the library:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Then using this will return just the decimal value:

```
Regex.Match("T.GS.+0.220kg", "\d+.\d+").Value
```

This particular expression looks for a digit or digits, followed by a point (dot), followed by another number of digits, so the previous points (in between T and G for example) aren't included.

This returns exactly `0.220`, you can then replace the string with any string variable and assign this expression as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you havn't worked with regular expressions before and want somthing that looks a little nicer. You could use the string.split method.

```
dim input as string = "T.GS.+0.220kg"
input = input.split("+")(1) ' which will grab the "0.220kg"
input = input.substring(0, input.length - 2) ' then filter off the last 2 chars
```

In english:

split the string into 2 seperate pieces grabing the part to the right of the first '+' symbol.

Then remove the last 2 chars from the end.